# How to cast / reinterpret Vector128<float> into Vector128<int> in .NET?

Tags: .net, simd, sse, intrinsics

I am looking for the .NET 3.0+ equivalent of the no-op x86 intrinsic [_mm_castps_si128](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_castps_si128&expand=617). How can I quick-cast a `Vector128<float>`  into a `Vector128<int>` so the bit-pattern stays the same.

Answer (score 2):

The intended way to do it is through the method [Vector128.As<U,V>()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.vector128.as?view=netcore-3.0), or [`.AsInt32()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.vector128.asint32?view=net-8.0)

```
Vector128<float> mf = Vector128.Create(42f);
Vector128<int> mi = mf.As<int, float>(); // acts as '_mm_castps_si128'
// or more simply mi = mf.AsInt32();
```

This just reinterprets the bits, e.g. if you want to extract the exponent field from the FP bit-pattern as an integer.

Or if the data wasn't really `float`s, like the result of a SIMD compare.  You can use the all-zero / all-one bis  as integer `0` / `-1` to count matches for example, `counts = Sse2.Subtract(counts, mi);`

Comment: This is not correct. As interprets the value as an integer, but doesnt cast. This means the original float value is read byte-for-byte as an int, which results in a very different number.

Comment: @TJHeuvel type-punning / reinterpreting is what ` _mm_castps_si128` does, which is what the OP asked for, both by name and confirming they want as a zero-instruction operation.  In Intel C intrinsics terminology, this is what "casting" a SIMD vector means, same in GCC or clang if you do `(__m128i)my_m128` it just reinterprets.  I'll retitle the question to say "reinterpret" to make that clear.

Comment: Converting with a `cvtps2dq` instruction (C intrinsic `_mm_cvtps_epi32`) is a different operation (producing new bit-patterns that as i32 represent the same or nearby values as the f32 elements did, unless they were out-of-range).  Perhaps both things can be covered by separate answers to this one question, just because search terminology makes it hard to distinguish, especially for folks who don't already know the answer or the C intrinsics terminology. And they're both trivial (one obviously-best way to do each; it doesn't get tricky until converting to u32 or i64 on x86 without AVX-512...).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to convert instead of reinterpret,  use the [`Vector128<float>.ConvertToInt32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.vector128.converttoint32?view=net-8.0#system-runtime-intrinsics-vector128-converttoint32(system-runtime-intrinsics-vector128((system-single)))) method.

To actually use this, it seems you need to use an ISA-specific intrinsic like Sse or AdvSimd, such as [`Sse2.ConvertToVector128Int32WithTruncation(vec_f128)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86.sse2.converttovector128int32withtruncation?view=net-8.0) to convert each of the four elements the same way as a scalar cast (with rounding toward 0.0 aka truncation) with a [`cvttps2dq`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvttps2dq) instruction. Equivalent to C `_mm_cvttps_epi32`, not `_mm_castps_si128`.

Or with AArch64 aka ARM64, `AdvSimd.ConvertToInt32RoundToZero(vec_f128)` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.arm.advsimd.converttoint32roundtozero?view=net-8.0))

`Vector128<float>.ConvertToInt32(vec)` doesn't actually compile.   (editor's note: at least not the way I tried; I don't know much C# but this is what I got to compile while trying to figure out if `ConvertToInt32` truncated towards 0 like scalar casts and `_mm_cvttps_epi32`, or if it used the current rounding mode (usually nearest) like the C intrinsic `_mm_cvtps_epi32`.)

For x86 / x64:

```
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86;

Vector128<int> foo(Vector128<float> vf)
{
//   Vector128<int> vi = vf.AsInt32();    // reinterpret

    Vector128<int> vi = Sse2.ConvertToVector128Int32(vf);  // cvtps2dq convert to a vector (with current rounding mode)
//   vi = Sse2.ConvertToVector128Int32WithTruncation(vf);  // cvttps2dq convert to a vector (with truncation)

    int low_scalar_cvt = Sse.ConvertToInt32(vf);   // cvtss2si  scalar conversion of low element (with current rounding mode)

// vi =  Vector128<float>.ConvertToInt32(vf);  // compile error. In theory should return a Vector128<int>

    return vi;
  //   Vector128<int> counts = Vector128.CreateScalar(0);   // xorps to zero a reg
  //   return Sse2.Subtract(counts, vi);                    // psubd to subtract with 32-bit int elements
}
```

(See the asm it compiles+JITs to on [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzgWwB8ABAJgEYBYAKGIAYACY8gOgCUBXAOwwEt8YLAJI8ovLrl5hcAbhr0mrTj36CRGMRKm4WADQAcSOdQD0J4gGYmpBgGEGAbxoMXDM5eeuAajDAZo5KT6ADziGAB8DABmEBAAFD5+AUHBUQA2ENgRDABuUQCUni5O1K4uZt6+/lCBIWGRObwMALy5USwAgrjqFqRx+TJlFbBhMFAADrAYaAxcEAyQXDljGAziuBocfrwQXDRFDInVtaE8DU2tAMq4MKQstrvLUBgAKhBHyfo9fXkD5SYLHIYca4UgAEwAjgtHisGP4GNhclVoAw4gB3XgYAAWCw4UFgPAYUAg3DB4gA5gx8BAwTBCqYAS5Gi0GNdbvcYc83h8akFvgB1TFYl5QbhgLI7LhxX6DNwAsBA4GgyHQpaw+GI5ZJKCojHYuGirjivi7ekHMIMDJogD6uHFaWwUGtCtWVxuHLVXIg32lBVlcsBGFwoMkLjt2AdOsWT0kuwYECilogaIYMDSMAEhPRQtx+JghOJpIpVJpdP21AOFWZrUOyN5IXSmQiHqer29PF6vr+Acg+HGvHTqfx0BYDBEcKxMGgAE8GLgsSS0mCmAB2BG17UneqVgHVlw82otlZvH0y/4ItK4eaI3v9wdjYlQGZzKkwbE06IkrjLmI6iNpCcYBuBEMAwDNxiDFhyyGXcLjaI8vR9P4Kg6S95lvAcYCHR9cB3XJeAQtsAFUkMGCoIyvdcMPvYcoAOMp6IPFJ6mhbggxZJj9HuWAshgS57UdOI6G7AMEGgEE4XmAAvMZryJGByXo4g1zZO5Lg4YANGwPw4kgNjcBmRoRLKEzTPPEENOXeFcA0rS/AYPUcV6OBgExNZCTTDN8yDaDXAAXxoMw/KAA))